# Angular http request after another but only care about first one

Tags: angular, http, rxjs

I have a scenario where I want to call an API and, if returns 200, I want to call another API but I'm only interested in the response of the first API called. Something like this:

```js
    const http1$ = of('response 1');
    // const http2$ = of('response 2');
    const http2$ = throwError('response 2');
    
    http1$.pipe(
      switchMap((response1) => http2$.pipe(map(() => response1)))
    ).subscribe(response1 => {
      // I need to get response 1 even if http2 fails which, in this case, won't work
      console.log(response1);
    });
```

The only solution that comes to my mind atm is having a subscribe to http2 in a tap or inside the subscribe of http1 but this is not a good practice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand the problem right, "piping" a `catchError` into the `map` operator should do the trick for you.

Something along these lines

```
http1$.pipe(
    switchMap((response1) => http2$.pipe(
        map(() => response1)).pipe(
            catchError(() => of(response1))
        )
    )
).subscribe(response1 => {
    // I need to get response 1 even if http2 fails which, in this case, won't work
    console.log(response1);
});
```

**EDIT AFTER THE COMMENT**
If instead you want to fire-and-forget http2$ after http1$ has returned, but are not interested at all in the result of http2$ (the forget part of fire-and-forget) and return immediately the response of http1$, then you may proceed like this

```
// first create a shared stream starting with http1$
const http1Shared$ = http1$.pipe(
    share()
);
// then use the shared stream to create a new stream which will trigger http2$ as soon as http1$ returns
// the use of the shared stream is to make sure http1$ is only called once
// you can catch the error and ignore it using catchError(() => EMPTY)
// EMPTY is an observable that completes immediately without emitting any value and without erroring
const stream2$ = http1Shared$.pipe(
    switchMap(() => http2$),
    catchError(() => EMPTY),
);

// then subscribe to both streams - the first one will be used to process the response from http1$
// the second one will be used to trigger http2$ as soon as http1$ returns but will ignore its response
http1Shared$.subscribe(response1 => {
    // I need to get response 1 even if http2 fails which, in this case, won't work
    console.log(response1);
});
stream2$.subscribe();
```

Comment: Tnks for the reply. I though about this after I post the question. But in this case I'm gonna need to wait for http2$ to return in order to get value response1.  To elaborate my question, http2$ should be async and not block response1 to get to the subscriber.

Comment: So, if I understand your comment right, you want http2$ to be triggered after http1$ has returned but also get the response of http1$ as soon as it is available, without having to wait for the response (or error) of http2$. Is this right?

Comment: This is what I needed, tnks a lot